# Sharing a subfolder of my home folder with Docker run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The command

`echo ~`

produces in my box:

bash: /home/jcabrerazuniga: Is a directory

I want to share the folder:

`echo ~` + '/myPrograms' (=  /home/jcabrerazuniga/myPrograms ) with an internal folder in a docker container as with:

```
docker run --name=dev_server --network=host --privileged \      
      -v `echo ~` + '/mypograms':/home/${USER} \  
      -it jcabrerazuniga/mycontainer:v1 /bin/bash
```

Is this possible? how?

Comment: If you need a privileged container with host networking and direct access to the host filesystem, it may be easier to just run the process directly on the host than to try to disable key Docker features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$HOME):

> $HOME is a Linux bash shell variable. It indicates the home directory of the current user

So, for you, you just need to use something like next:

```
docker run -v ${HOME}/mypograms:/home/${USER} -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```